# In Next.js, calling router.push() after router.refresh() cannot refresh the current page

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I am trying to write a Next.js full-stack application.

To put it simply, on my posts list page - server component, there is a create post button - client-component. When the button is clicked, I want to create a new post, refresh the current posts list page using `router.refresh()`, and then use `router.push("/posts/xxxxx")` to navigate to the detail page. On the detail page, there is a `<Link href="/posts">Back</Link>` that navigates back to the posts list page.

Next.js verion: `next@14.1.0`

Example code:

```js
// posts/page.txs
import { notFound } from "next/navigation"

import { db } from "@/lib/db"
import { getCurrentUser } from "@/lib/session"
import { DashboardShell } from "@/components/dashboard/dashboard-shell"
import { DashboardHeader } from "@/components/dashboard/header"
import { PostCreateButton } from "@/components/dashboard/post/post-create-button"
import { PostItem } from "@/components/dashboard/post/post-item"

export default async function PostPage() {
  const user = await getCurrentUser()

  if (!user.isAdmin) {
    return notFound()
  }

  // query posts here.
  const posts = await db.post.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      published: true,
      createdAt: true,
    },
    where: {
      authorId: user.id,
    },
    orderBy: {
      updatedAt: "desc",
    },
  })

  // after router.refresh(), this log printed and a new post is found here.
  console.log("query posts", `post count: ${posts.length}`)

  return (
    <DashboardShell>
      <DashboardHeader heading="Posts" text="Create and manage posts.">
        {/* post create button here. a client component */}
        <PostCreateButton />
      </DashboardHeader>
      <div>
        {posts.length && (
          <div className="divide-y divide-border rounded-md border">
            {posts.map((post) => (
              <PostItem key={post.id} post={post} />
            ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </DashboardShell>
  )
}
```

```js
// post-create-button.tsx

"use client"

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { ButtonProps, buttonVariants } from "@/components/ui/button"
import { toast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast"
import { Icons } from "@/components/icons"

interface PostCreateButtonProps extends ButtonProps {}

export function PostCreateButton({
  className,
  variant,
  ...props
}: PostCreateButtonProps) {
  const router = useRouter()

  async function onClick() {

    const response = await fetch("/api/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: "Untitled Post",
      }),
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
      return toast({
        title: "Something went wrong.",
        description: "Your post was not created. Please try again.",
        variant: "destructive",
      })
    }

    const post = await response.json()

    // This forces a cache invalidation.
    router.refresh()

    // strange thing here
    router.push(`/editor/${post.id}`)
  }

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
    >
      New post
    </button>
  )
}
```

However, when I click the `Back` link to return to the posts list page, the newly created post does not appear.

Here is my full code: https://github.com/boh5/Aero/tree/strange

However, if I remove the `router.push` and simply stay on the posts list page after creating a new post, the newly created post will show up. Alternatively, if I introduce a short delay after `router.refresh` and then use `router.push` to navigate to the detail page, it works well.

And if I downgrade `next@14.1.0` to `next@13.3.2-canary.13`, it works.

So, I am confused as to why calling `router.push` after `router.refresh` does not refresh the current page.